# Social Framework Web Page Thumbnail iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, thumbnails, social-framework

I have implemented the Social Framework in my app, but when sharing the url link via SLComposeViewController the web page thumbnail not showing. How to show the thumbnail?

Here is the code:

```
SLComposeViewController *fbSheetOBJ = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
    [fbSheetOBJ setInitialText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Everything you need to travel all in one app. Download %@ now!\nHelp you travel more.",[hiConfig AppName]]];
    [fbSheetOBJ addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/hibali/id712909255?ls=1&mt=8"]];
```

for now it's look like this

[image: no thumbnail]

I want it to look like this (posting directly from facebook site)

[image: with thumbnail]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I think you have to remove the stuff at the end of the URL. Before:

```
[fbSheetOBJ addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/hibali/id712909255?ls=1&mt=8"]];
```

After:

```
[fbSheetOBJ addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/hibali/id712909255"]];
```

That should do the trick. Let me know. Cheers.

Comment: Update: Ok so according to this link [Apples Technical Q&A QA1633](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1633/_index.html) it seems the "mt=8" should be included. Not sure if it makes a difference since it seems to work without it. The Q&A also says to get the link from iTunes. And it says "...These URLs are great for linking to your app or company page in the App Store or Mac App Store from your website or inside your app..."